# How to make a dashed rectangle with consistent spacing in manim?

Tags: python, algorithm-animation, manim

How to create a dashed rectangle with equally spaced dashes on both edges in manim? I've tried inheriting from `Rectangle` and adding dashes the same way as it is implemented for `DashedLine` but it produces very different densities on the longer and shorter edges. Here is my attempt (code derived from MIT licensed manim repository):

```
%%manim HighLevelIntuition -l -q
from manimlib_imports import *

class DashedRectangle(Rectangle):
    CONFIG = {
        "dash_length": DEFAULT_DASH_LENGTH,
        "dash_spacing": None,
        "positive_space_ratio": 0.5,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Rectangle.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ps_ratio = self.positive_space_ratio
        num_dashes = self.calculate_num_dashes(ps_ratio)
        dashes = DashedVMobject(
            self,
            num_dashes=num_dashes,
            positive_space_ratio=ps_ratio
        )
        self.clear_points()
        self.add(*dashes)

    def calculate_num_dashes(self, positive_space_ratio):
        try:
            full_length = self.dash_length / positive_space_ratio
            return int(np.ceil(
                self.get_arc_length() / full_length
            ))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 1

class HighLevelIntuition(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        self.play(ShowCreation(DashedRectangle(width=10, height=2)))
```

And that's how it looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: Also, I would love to see "manim" tag for https://github.com/3b1b/manim library - this got very popular quickly and there are already some (unfortunately not tagged) questions on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
class DashedRectangle(VGroup):
    CONFIG={
        "num_dashes": 30,
        "positive_space_ratio": 0.5,
        "width":5,
        "height":4
    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        VGroup.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)
        h1=[ORIGIN,UP*self.height]
        w1=[UP*self.height,UP*self.height+RIGHT*self.width]
        h2=[UP*self.height+RIGHT*self.width,RIGHT*self.width]
        w2=[RIGHT*self.width,ORIGIN]
        alpha=self.width/self.height
        divs=self.num_dashes

        n_h=int(divs/(2*(alpha+1)))
        n_w=int(alpha*n_h)
        dashedrectangle=VGroup()
        for n,l in zip([n_w,n_h],[[w1,w2],[h1,h2]]):
            for side in l:
                line=VMobject()
                line.set_points_as_corners(side)
                dashedrectangle.add(DashedVMobject(line,num_dashes=n,positive_space_ratio=self.positive_space_ratio))
        self.add(dashedrectangle[0],dashedrectangle[3],dashedrectangle[1],dashedrectangle[2])



class DashedRectangleScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rec=DashedRectangle()
        rec.move_to(ORIGIN)
        self.play(ShowCreation(rec))
        self.wait()
```

[DashedSquare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeqGk.png)

Comment: Thank you! This is a clever workaround, though the problematic part would be that the ShowCreation() would not work as expected (each edge would be drawn independently).

Comment: @krassowski Ok, try that.

Comment: This works great! Just because it seems that you are new to the SO - it is considered a good practice to provide some explanations and comments in addition to the code. I would even accept an answer which only points me in the right direction and allows me to develop a working solution ;)

Comment: @krassowski Ok. perfect.